# Classes don't autoload with Adyen php-api-library?

Tags: php, composer-php, adyen

I am trying to get the Adyen php-api-library working, but i get the message:
Fatal error: Class 'Service\Payment' not found

The error message makes me to believe the class payment is not being loaded, but how do i make sure / fix this?? I thought composer would do the job.

I am devolping on a local XAMPP (mac)
- i have installed with composer
- simple test.php

```
>    composer require adyen/php-api-library Using version ^1.5 for
> adyen/php-api-library ./composer.json has been created Loading
> composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies
> (including require-dev) Package operations: 3 installs, 0 updates, 0
> removals
>   - Installing psr/log (1.0.2): Loading from cache
>   - Installing monolog/monolog (1.24.0): Downloading (100%)         
>   - Installing adyen/php-api-library (1.5.3): Downloading (100%)          monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log
> messages to AWS services like DynamoDB) monolog/monolog suggests
> installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB
> server) monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending
> log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required)) monolog/monolog
> suggests installing ext-mongo (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB
> server) monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow
> sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server) monolog/monolog suggests
> installing mongodb/mongodb (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB
> server via PHP Driver) monolog/monolog suggests installing
> php-amqplib/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server
> using php-amqplib) monolog/monolog suggests installing
> php-console/php-console (Allow sending log messages to Google Chrome)
> monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log
> messages to Rollbar) monolog/monolog suggests installing
> ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search
> server) monolog/monolog suggests installing sentry/sentry (Allow
> sending log messages to a Sentry server) Writing lock file Generating
> autoload files
```

test.php

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new \Adyen\Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Adyen PHP Api Library Example");
$client->setUsername("xxxx");
$client->setPassword("xxxxx");
$client->setXApiKey("xxxxxxxxxxx");
$client->setEnvironment(\Adyen\Environment::TEST);

$service = new Service\Payment($client);

$json = '{
      "card": {
        "number": "4111111111111111",
        "expiryMonth": "03",
        "expiryYear": "2030",
        "cvc": "737",
        "holderName": "John Smith"
      },
      "amount": {
        "value": 1500,
        "currency": "EUR"
      },
      "reference": "payment-test",
      "merchantAccount": "ourshopcom"
}';

$params = json_decode($json, true);

$result = $service->authorise($params);
```

Comment: Did you try, `\Adyen\Service\Payment($client);`, if in doubt always [check the file](https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-php-api-library/blob/develop/src/Adyen/Service/Payment.php).

Comment: ......ah totally didn't look into the path

Comment: ..but still no working code. I have edited the card expire date as stated in the docs. But still i get '
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Adyen\AdyenException' with message 'Not allowed' '

Comment: Thats diff from the original issue, I suggest you look up on how to catch exceptions in PHP http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php and `Not allowed` probably means your not allowed to issue the api call as its not a php error but a defined exception which you are meant to handle. The issue could be any of them variables in the json payload. YOUR MERCHANT ACCOUNT is obviously not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs on the GitHub for that is wrong. I looked at the source. 
That class is in namespace "Adyen\Service".

Change your code as follows:

```
$service = new Adyen\Service\Payment($client);
```